# Why does McConnell voting against the Fed nominee allow him to advance it again later?

Tags: united-states, congress

Article's discussing Judy Shelton's nomination say something like:

> The procedural vote ultimately failed 47 to 50, with Mr. McConnell changing his vote from agreeing to advance the nomination to opposing it so he could revive it before the end of the lame-duck session. [NYT](https://www.nytimes.com/2020/11/17/business/economy/judy-shelton-fed-vote.html)

Why does McConnell voting it down mean he could advance it? It implies if he had voted "yay" he could not advance it again.

Comment: They don't want sore losers to keep revisiting the same stuff, over and over. The loophole is voting FOR the thing you are against, so you can later say "I'm not revisiting, I was on the winning side and had a change of heart, so this should be re-opened."